# Design Tic tac toe game

Tags: python, game, tic-tac-toe

Today I had an interview, where I was asked to solve this question:

**Design Tic tac toe game**

Game rules:

> Design a simple tic tac game with 2 modes for 3*3 matrix. At the
>   beginning, ask if single player or two player mode has to be played
>   (more details on the mode below).
>
> The players input position on matrix by inputting 2 integers, like:
>
> ```
> 0,0    0,1    0,2
>
> 1,0    1,1    1,2
>
> 2,0    2,1    2,2
> ```
>
> If anywhere player gives incorrect input, he has to be prompted to
>   give the right value again.
>
> Print the updated matrix after every input. Example: after 3 moves,
>   one game might look like
>
> ```
> 1    1    _
>
> 2    _    _
>
> _     _    _
> ```
>
> *Single player mode*
>
> In this mode, player plays against the computer.
>   You’ve to first assign 0’s or  X’s to the Player. X’s play first. The
>   computer can randomly place its assigned symbol at any available
>   position within the matrix.
>
> *Two player mode*
>
> In this mode, two players play against each other.
>
> The game ends when either player wins, or there are no moves left
>   (draw). At the end of game, print the final result Ask if the player
>   wants to play another game, and start a new game/end the game
>   accordingly.

I got the feedback that complexity could be improved, How to improve it?
and how to make it more readable

Code goes below:

```
def get_input(mat, player):
    input_value = map(int, raw_input().split(','))
    while(validate_input(mat, input_value) == False):
        print "not correct input"
        input_value = map(int,raw_input().split(','))
    mat[input_value[0]][input_value[1]] = player
    return input_value

def validate_input(mat, input_value):
    x = input_value[0]
    y = input_value[1]
    if x not in [0,1,2] or y not in [0,1,2]:
        return False
    if mat[x][y]:
        return False
    return True

def switch_play(player):
    player = 2 if player==1 else 1
    return player

def print_game(mat):
    print mat

def get_random(mat):
    input_value = [random.randint(0,2)] *2
    while(validate_input(mat, input_value) == False):
        print "not correct input"
        input_value = [random.randint(0,2)] *2

    mat[input_value[0]][input_value[1]] = 2
    return input_value 


def game_completed(mat):
    if not game_won(mat):
        for i in xrange(3):
            for j in xrange(3):
                if not mat[i][j]:
                    return False

    return True

def game_won(mat):
    for i in xrange(3):
        row = mat[i]
        if len(set(mat[i])) == 1 and set(mat[i]) != {0}: 
            print 'won the game:player', mat[i][0]
            return True
    for i in xrange(3):
        col = [row[i] for row in mat]
        if len(set(col)) == 1 and set(col)!={0}:
            print 'won the game:player', mat[0][i]
            return True
        dia1 = [mat[i][i] for i in xrange(3)]
        dia2 = [mat[2-i][i] for i in xrange(3)]
        if (len(set(dia1)) == 1 and set(dia1)!={0}):
                print 'won game: player', mat[0][0]
                return True
        if (len(set(dia2)) == 1 and set(dia2)!={0}):
                print 'won game: player', mat[2][2]
                return True
        return False            



print "hoose player 1 your type, X or O?"
p1 = raw_input()
p2 = 'O' if p1=='X' else 'X'
player = 1
mat = [[0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]]
computer_playing = False
while True:
    if computer_playing and player==2:
        get_random(mat, player)
    else:
        get_input(mat, player)
    print_game(mat)
    if game_completed(mat):
        print "game is completed"
        break
    player = switch_play(player)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your interviewer meant that you can improve checking the winning situation and do it in \$O(1)\$ time by keeping track of the scores in rows, columns and both diagonals (total 8 variables for 3x3 board):

```
[row1, row2, row3, column1, column2, column3, diagonal, anti-diagonal]
```

Then, you can increment these value by 1 in case of "player 1" and decrement by one in case of "player 2". This will lead to only checking these 8 values (or you can also use the fact that you know where the last move took place) for 3 or -3 for a winning situation. You can find out more about this idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18668901/771848).

Or, you can go over all the possible winning combinations like suggested [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/108756/24208) or [here](https://gist.github.com/rpip/5608979).