# Simple two-player Tic-Tac-Toe

Tags: python, python-2.x, tic-tac-toe

How can I improve this simple code to look better, concise and elegant? I've been learning Python for 2 weeks. I knew about basic Python stuff and some algorithms and data structure as well. I made a Tic-Tac-Toe game and it worked well but the problem is that I can't write code in a Pythonic way.

```
#importing libraries

from __future__ import print_function
import random
import os
import sys
#clear output 
clear = lambda : os.system('cls')

#creating display board 
def display_board(board):
    clear()
    print('   |   |')
    print(' ' + board[7] + ' | ' + board[8] + ' | ' + board[9])
    print('   |   |')
    print('-----------')
    print('   |   |')
    print(' ' + board[4] + ' | ' + board[5] + ' | ' + board[6])
    print('   |   |')
    print('-----------')
    print('   |   |')
    print(' ' + board[1] + ' | ' + board[2] + ' | ' + board[3])
    print('   |   |')
#getting input from player
def player_input():
    marker = ' '
    while not (marker == 'X' or marker == 'O'):
        marker = raw_input('Choose O or X to play!').upper()
    if marker == 'X':
        return ('X','O')
    else:
        return ('O','X')
#place marker on borard
def place_marker(board,marker,postion):
    board[position] = marker
#Checking win or not 
def win_check (board,mark):
    return ((board[7] == mark and board[8] == mark and board[9] == mark) or # across the top
    (board[4] == mark and board[5] == mark and board[6] == mark) or # across the middle
    (board[1] == mark and board[2] == mark and board[3] == mark) or # across the bottom
    (board[7] == mark and board[4] == mark and board[1] == mark) or # down the middle
    (board[8] == mark and board[5] == mark and board[2] == mark) or # down the middle
    (board[9] == mark and board[6] == mark and board[3] == mark) or # down the right side
    (board[7] == mark and board[5] == mark and board[3] == mark) or # diagonal
    (board[9] == mark and board[5] == mark and board[1] == mark)) # diagonal
# who first to go

def choose_first():
    if random.randint(0,1) == 0:
        return 'Player 1'
    else:
        return 'Player 2'

# checking space is free or not
def check_space(board,position):
    return board[position] == ' '
#full board check 
def full_board_check (board):
    for i in range (1,10):
        if check_space(board,i):
            return False
    return True
#player choice
def player_choice (board):
    position = ' '
    while position not in '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'.split() or not check_space(board, int(position)):
        position = raw_input('Choose number input 1-9')
    return int(position)
#asking replay or not 
def replay():

    return raw_input('Do you want to play again? Enter Yes or No: ').lower().startswith('y')
print('Welcome to Tic Tac Toe Game!')

while True:
    # Reset the board
    theBoard = [' '] * 10
    player1_marker, player2_marker = player_input()
    turn = choose_first()
    print(turn + ' will go first.')
    game_on = True

    while game_on:
        if turn == 'Player 1':
            # Player1's turn.

            display_board(theBoard)
            position = player_choice(theBoard)
            place_marker(theBoard, player1_marker, position)

            if win_check(theBoard, player1_marker):
                display_board(theBoard)
                print('Congratulations! You have won the game!')
                game_on = False
            else:
                if full_board_check(theBoard):
                    display_board(theBoard)
                    print('The game is a draw!')
                    break
                else:
                    turn = 'Player 2'

        else:
            # Player2's turn.

            display_board(theBoard)
            position = player_choice(theBoard)
            place_marker(theBoard, player2_marker, position)

            if win_check(theBoard, player2_marker):
                display_board(theBoard)
                print('Player 2 has won!')
                game_on = False
            else:
                if full_board_check(theBoard):
                    display_board(theBoard)
                    print('The game is a tie!')
                    break
                else:
                    turn = 'Player 1'

    if not replay():
        break
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have created a working game, kuddo's for that.

## The good

- Some parts of the code are divided into functions
- (nearly) made this work for both python3 and python2

  > `NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined`

  Adding this to the top of the file would circumvent that

  ```
  try:
      raw_input()
  except NameError:
      raw_input = input
  ```

  This is tagged with 2.7, but if there is no specific reason for it. I suggest to start writing in 3.x

## The bad

- This code is begin suffocated, [#add a few blank lines. [PEP8]](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#blank-lines)
- Stick to DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)

  You are repeating yourself in some areas

  > ```
  > display_board(theBoard)
  > position = player_choice(theBoard)
  > place_marker(theBoard, player1_marker, position)
  > if win_check(theBoard, player1_marker):
  >     display_board(theBoard)
  >     print('Congratulations! You have won the game!')
  >     game_on = False
  > else:
  >     if full_board_check(theBoard):
  >         display_board(theBoard)
  >         print('The game is a draw!')
  >         break
  >     else:
  >         turn = 'Player 2'
  > ```
- Use `'string'.format()` over string concants

  At your `display_board(board)` function for example

## Revised code

```
import random
try:
    raw_input()
except NameError:
    raw_input = input

# This idea is shamelessly stolen from!
# https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/108738/python-tic-tac-toe-game
WIN_COMBINATIONS = [(1, 2, 3),
                    (4, 5, 6),
                    (7, 8, 9),
                    (1, 4, 7),
                    (2, 5, 8),
                    (3, 6, 9),
                    (1, 5, 9),
                    (3, 5, 7)]

def display_board(board):
    print('''   |   |  
 {} | {} | {}
   |   |
-----------
   |   |
 {} | {} | {} 
   |   |
-----------
   |   |
 {} | {} | {}
   |   |'''.format(*board[1:10]))

def player_input():
    marker = ' '
    while not (marker == 'X' or marker == 'O'):
        marker = raw_input('Player 1, Choose O or X to play!').upper()
    if marker == 'X':
        return {'Player 1': 'X', 'Player 2': 'O'}
    else:
        return {'Player 2': 'X', 'Player 1': 'O'}

def win_check (board):
    return any(board[a] != ' ' and board[a] == board[b] == board[c] for a, b, c in WIN_COMBINATIONS)

def choose_first(players):
    random_player = 'Player {}'.format(random.randint(1, 2))
    return random_player, players[random_player]

def full_check (board):
    return all(b != ' ' for b in board)

def player_choice(board):
    while True:
        try:
            position = int(raw_input('Choose number input 1-9'))
            if position in range(1, 9) and board[position] == ' ':
                return position
        except ValueError:
            pass

def replay():
    return raw_input('Do you want to play again? Enter Yes or No: ').lower().startswith('y')

def ttt():
    board = [' ' for _ in range(10)]
    players = player_input()
    name, player_marker = choose_first(players)
    print('{} with marker {} will go first.'.format(name, player_marker))
    while True:
        position = player_choice(board)
        board[position] = player_marker
        display_board(board)
        if win_check(board):
            print('Congratulations {}! You have won the game!'.format(name))
            break

        if full_check(board):
            print('Congratulations {} and {}! You have a tie!'.format(players.keys()))
            break

        name = 'Player 1' if name == 'Player 2' else 'Player 2'
        player_marker = players[name]
        print(name, player_marker)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Welcome to Tic Tac Toe Game!')
    while True:
        ttt()
        if not replay():
            break
```

Comment: For the answer that fix this game in line: print('Congratulations {} and {}! You have a tie!'.format(players.keys())) you need to add the `players.values()` because its dictionary that key talk about the name (player 1) and the values is about the player_marker.

Comment: I have a serious issue with starting the module with `try:raw_input()`. If you're running python 2.x it will actually require you to input something. If it's as much of a function as I'd expect based on my experience with python 3.x, then just leave out the parentheses and it should work as desired.