# Tic-Tac-Toe code using Python with Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tic-tac-toe, tkinter

`I made this Tic-Tac-Toe game first, by using user input in the console here:
https://pastebin.com/6zLjrWcf
, and now new and improved using Tkinter:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import time


def create_button(relx, rely):
    button = tk.Button(width=10, height=2, command=lambda: callback(button))
    button.place(relx=relx, rely=rely)
    return button


def check_win():                     
    if (buttons[0]['text'] == buttons[1]['text'] == buttons[2]['text'] != '') or \
            (buttons[3]['text'] == buttons[4]['text'] == buttons[5]['text'] != '') or \
            (buttons[6]['text'] == buttons[7]['text'] == buttons[8]['text'] != '') or \
            (buttons[0]['text'] == buttons[3]['text'] == buttons[6]['text'] != '') or \
            (buttons[1]['text'] == buttons[4]['text'] == buttons[7]['text'] != '') or \
            (buttons[2]['text'] == buttons[5]['text'] == buttons[8]['text'] != '') or \
            (buttons[2]['text'] == buttons[4]['text'] == buttons[6]['text'] != '') or \
            (buttons[0]['text'] == buttons[4]['text'] == buttons[8]['text'] != ''):
        return True
    else:
        return False


def callback(button):
    global turn, x
    if x == 1:
        time.sleep(1)
        game.quit()
    invalid['text'] = ''
    if button['text'] != '':
        invalid['text'] = 'Invalid space try again'
        return
    button['text'] = turn
    if check_win():
        invalid['text'] = 'Player ' + turn + ' WINS!!!!!'
        x = 1
    turn = ('0' if turn == 'X' else 'X')
    label_button['text'] = 'PLAYER ' + turn + '\'S TURN.'


x = 0
turn = 'X'
game = tk.Tk()
game.title('TicTacToe')
game.geometry('700x500')
buttons = []
for i in range(1, 10):
    button_created = create_button(0.25 if i / 3 <= 1 else 0.45 if i / 3 <= 2 else 0.65, 0.2 if i in [1, 4, 7] else
                                   0.4 if i in [2, 5, 8] else 0.6)
    buttons.append(button_created)
label_button = ttk.Button(game, text='PLAYER ' + turn + '\'S TURN.', style='Fun.TButton', width=20, state='disabled')
label_button.pack(pady=30)
invalid = tk.Label(text='')
invalid.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.12)
game.mainloop()
```

My main question is if there is a way to compact check_win()?
Also please review the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Let us begin with some layout. This is a typical grid use case so that you won't have to manually manage grid. At the lowest level, a grid structure essentially places buttons by calculating coordinates. But this gets tedious over time, that's why a grid layout is provided. Also, it was a clever way of cheking win by being symbol agnostic. A normal tic tac toe game would have used checkwin(symbol) to determine win.

### On strings

To escape `'` within `' '` you can use `"` instead. From

```py
'\'S TURN.'
```

to

```py
"'S TURN."
```

and you can also use string formatting to clear up some clutter.

```py
"PLAYER {}'S TURN.".format(turn)
```

### On layout

Modifying your `create_button` function to this allows a grid structure

```py
def create_button(x, y):
    button = tk.Button(width=10, height=2, command=lambda: callback(button))
    button.grid(row=x, column=y)
    return button
```

Then we modify others since different layouts can't be mixed

```py
label_button = ttk.Button(
                        game, 
                        text="PLAYER {}'S TURN.".format(turn), 
                        style='Fun.TButton', width=20, 
                        state='disabled')
label_button.grid(row=0, column=1)
invalid = tk.Label(text='')
invalid.grid(row=4, column=1)
```

adding the buttons can be then done as

```py
buttons = []

buttons.append(create_button(1, 0))
buttons.append(create_button(1, 1))
buttons.append(create_button(1, 2))
buttons.append(create_button(2, 0))
buttons.append(create_button(2, 1))
buttons.append(create_button(2, 2))
buttons.append(create_button(3, 0))
buttons.append(create_button(3, 1))
buttons.append(create_button(3, 2))
```

You can use a loop for the row and `itertools.cycle` for the `0, 1, 2` if you want to simplify it.

### The `check_win` function

- Simplifying if

Adding a `()` to if statements allows you to write `or` without `\`

```
if ... :
    ...

to

if (...):
    ...
```

thus the win_function can be simplified from

```py
if (buttons[0]['text'] == buttons[1]['text'] == buttons[2]['text'] != '') or \
(buttons[3]['text'] == buttons[4]['text'] == buttons[5]['text'] != '') or \
```

to

```py
def check_win():
    if (
        (buttons[0]['text'] == buttons[1]['text'] == buttons[2]['text'] != '') or
        (buttons[3]['text'] == buttons[4]['text'] == buttons[5]['text'] != '') or
        ...
        ):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

- Simplifying values write-up

This can also be further simplified by defining a function to replace `buttons[0]['text']`

```py
def btext(i):
    return buttons[i]['text']
```

and using it

```py
def check_win():
    if (
        (btext(0) == btext(1) == btext(2) != '') or
        (btext(3) == btext(4) == btext(5) != '') or
        (btext(6) == btext(7) == btext(8) != '') or
        (btext(0) == btext(3) == btext(6) != '') or
        (btext(1) == btext(4) == btext(7) != '') or
        (btext(2) == btext(5) == btext(8) != '') or
        (btext(2) == btext(4) == btext(6) != '') or
        (btext(0) == btext(6) == btext(8) != '')
        ):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

### On architecture

A common pattern is the MVC (Model, View, Controller). While checking and updating gui directly works here, you might consider adding states in a structure like this:

```py
board = [
    ['', '', ''],
    ['', '', ''],
    ['', '', '']
]
```

Operations are done on this and the gui is updated according to this.

Answer (score -1):

From : 
[Python Tic Tac Toe Game](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/108738/python-tic-tac-toe-game)

```
    win_commbinations = ((0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8), (0, 3, 6), (1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (0, 4, 8), (2, 4, 6))

for a in win_commbinations:
            if board[a[0]] == board[a[1]] == board[a[2]] == "X":
                print("Player 1 Wins!\n")
                print("Congratulations!\n")
                return True

            if board[a[0]] == board[a[1]] == board[a[2]] == "O":
                print("Player 2 Wins!\n")
                print("Congratulations!\n")
                return True
        for a in range(9):
            if board[a] == "X" or board[a] == "O":
                count += 1
            if count == 9:
                print("The game ends in a Tie\n")
                return True
```

This alternative solution is a bit cleaner + includes a "Tie" check, which your original solution doesn't check ( just remove if you consider it irrelevant ofc )

Comment: You have not reviewed the code, but instead presented your own solution. While the code may improve some aspects, it does not have a tkinter GUI like the original code does.